# Fuel price actually used in the industry

Tags: fuel, terminology

I know it's a bit off-topic but I guess some of the terminology used in the aircraft community is the same as in marine transportation.

I know that both aircraft and marine vessels use fuel. But if I'm looking at the fuel prices on a commodities exchange, I guess the price is a bit different from the actual prices someone must pay for fuel used in the industry.

Do you have a name/term for fuel prices used in the industry, like fuel industrial price or something like that?

Comment: Not clear.  Are you looking for the term "price at the pump"?  Jet fuel is not even listed on any commodity exchange that I am aware of.   Jet fuel is used by private and commercial.   What is the term in marine transportation?

Comment: It's also important to note that large airlines do a large amount of [hedging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_%28finance%29) when it comes to fuel. They buy contracts for oil futures on the commodities market in advance to provide price stabilization. Thus their true cost for fuel (the "pump price" as adjusted by the hedge price and the size of the hedge at any given time) will depend entirely on the airline's hedging strategy at that moment.

Comment: "*marine vessels*" actually burn everything, and with the least efficient engines: [How 16 ships create as much pollution as all the cars in the world](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-1229857/How-16-ships-create-pollution-cars-world.html). That's the way we get low cost stuff from China. Low cost for our generation, low life four our children.

Answer (score 2):

Jet Fuel is not listed on the commodities exchange, at least not according to [this list.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_traded_commodities) For what its worth small boats use regular car gas or diesel fuel and some larger ships are powered by [fuel oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_oil) but they use boilers as opposed to a reciprocating engine like on smaller boats. Small boat gas tends to command a higher price because it can not because its any different than car gas. This is largely because you cant pull a big boat and take it to the gas station to fill it up every time you need fuel. AvGas for piston pounders is 110 or 100 octane low led. This is every similar to car gas (but higher octane and leaded). It is more expensive since it is taxed differently. Jet Fuel is effectively kerosene.

In the end of the day these are all crude oil byproducts so if you are looking for a commodity price the price of crude oil will effect the price of aviation fuels the same way it effects the price of car and boat fuels. Crude oil prices are about as close as you are going to get.

Answer (score 2):

Oil/fuel trading is not really my field of expertise, but IATA provides an overview of jet fuel prices at [their website](http://www.iata.org/publications/economics/fuel-monitor/Pages/price-analysis.aspx). 
They show the current average price for various parts of the world.

The data is sourced from [Platts](http://www.platts.com/jetfuel), an organisation that tracks many energy / petrochemical commodity prices.